# Unable to "Upload model zip" to Cloud Annotations to autolabel my dataset

Tags: ibm-cloud, labeling

I labeled 21 images for classification (only one tag) and I'm aware of the small size of my training data, I'm just testing. Then I used the button "Train in Colab", I trained the model and saved the .zip file. (I did not modify the code at all, I only changed the credentials to match my bucket.

Then I went back to Cloud Annotations and tried to upload my model to do Autolabeling by clicking File>Upload model zip. But after selecting my zip file the web app hangs in Saving... ([Photo of the message after clicking Upload model zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVWnE.png)). The button "No model available" stays.

I have literally waited for hours and nothing changes, the browser console gives no error message. I have tried with firefox, chrome, and edge having the same issue. I also have done the complete process more than three times and still no luck.

Anyone having the same issue? Or any way to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. I followed the tutorial and got to this last step. There is no indication of any error. No javascript errors getting thrown. No network activity. Just a UI update of "Saving..."

*Update:
I was able to get this to work by unziping and reziping it locally. It seems that the zip algorithm used by the python library doesn't get along with the js one used by IBM