# Unable to upload model zip to Cloud Annotations

Tags: ibm-cloud, labeling

I am using IBM's Cloud Annotations tool to label about 400 images. I have followed the instructions on the web and managed to train and download a zip file containing a model from Colab. But when I try to upload it back to use the Auto Label function, it gets stuck on "Saving..." forever. I tried the solution suggested here: 
[Unable to "Upload model zip" to Cloud Annotations to autolabel my dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68250736/unable-to-upload-model-zip-to-cloud-annotations-to-autolabel-my-dataset)

but it did not help. If anyone came across this problem and has a solution I would very appreciate it.

Comment: Stack overflow is for questions concerning programming not for advice on using non-programming tools.

Comment: @Xypron 1. The question I linked is similar to mine, it is on this site, and he got a helpful answer (to him at least)
2. The topics FAQ mentions "software tools commonly used by programmers", this in my opinion qualifies as one used by ML programmers